# How to add FCM Notification Trailing Image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons

Hey guys I want to include icon to my Flutter FCM notification like the below image How to do that Any help ? I want to add trailing Icon or Image

[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcdG7.jpg)

I want to Know How to Implement it in Flutter Android & iOS app

Comment: Check this link https://blog.devgenius.io/image-push-notification-advanced-in-flutter-ios-android-f2b8eefaa7f4